# Select last two element in div but not if there are only two

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like to use `nth-child` to select the last two element in a div. I know that I can do this using `nth-child(-n+2)`. But if there are only two element in there, it shouldn't select anything. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also consider `nth-last-child()` and create a complex selector like below:

```css
.container {
  border:2px solid red;
}
.container * {
  height:10px;
  margin:5px;
  background:blue;
}

.container *:nth-last-child(-n + 2):not(:nth-child(-n + 2)), /* select last two that aren't first two*/
.container *:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(2) { /* select the second when there is 3 items */
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div></div>
</div>
```